# Change default homepage

Tags: magento-1.9

I have installed sample data on magento(Madison Island), It has default homepage set. I have created new page called test (`cms>pages>create page`).
When i open my localhost, test page should appear first rather than homepage of madison island. How can i do it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Go to

```
Admin panel -> System -> Configuration -> General (Left) -> Web > Default Pages ->  CMS Home Page
```

Select your new page from Upper left corner's drop-down.

Answer (score 1):

In the admin you go to `System -> Configuration -> Web -> Default Pages`

You will have to change to the website / store view that you want to change (the dropdown in the upper left corner).

Answer (score 0):

```
Just Rename folder:
M_1.9_Framework_folder/app/design/frontend 
TO 
M_1.9_Framework_folder/app/design/frontend.disabled

This will block the store front site and allow only admin panel access.
```