# Home page is not Displaying

Tags: magento-1.9, configuration, cms, home

Displaying error like :

> There was no Home CMS page configured or found..

All other pages are working..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change default homepage](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/87812/change-default-homepage)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely caused by a missing configured home page.

To fix that, go to the backend under **System > Configuration > Web > Default Pages**

Change the store you're working on using the scope dropdown at the top left corner.

Now you can change the CMS page under Home Page CMS.

**Save the configuration**

Comment: Just to add to this - make sure the choosen CMS page is enabled for that particular store view.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the Default page when you hit the domain url. You can set this from your admin panel under **System** > **Configuration** > **Web** > **Default Pages**. Select the cms page from the field CMS Home Page.